# how can Create my own Elementor template library

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

can you help me how can Create my own Elementor template library for my own theme
I'm Writing a theme and I need Create my own library for my own theme
I saw on GitHub  and find some good repositories but has one problem:
you are adding a new template but the default Elementor library is deleted this is not good for my theme

can you help me please

Comment: Please share the GitHub repositories you referred, check how posts with post type `elementor_library` are generated. Check this https://github.com/analogwp/analogwp-templates/blob/develop/inc/api/class-local.php

Comment: This was the repositories I said it is:https://github.com/dinhtungdu/custom-elementor-source/tree/example/
this is very good  but has one problem: you are adding a new template but the default Elementor library is deleted
if you know how to fixed this bug please help me 
thanks

Comment: Check the method `create_page` https://github.com/analogwp/analogwp-templates/blob/develop/inc/api/class-local.php#L216 which create either page or template depends on second parameter `$with_page` is true or false

Comment: this repository is good but I can't add it to my theme 
(sorry my English language is bad I hope understand )Can you show me other codes?
That I can use them in my project